# dpkg fatal error while installing libxmlsec1:armh package

Tags: pi-3b+, raspbian-buster, apt, packages, dpkg

I am getting the following error while executing the following code on raspberry pi 3B+:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libxmlsec1:armhf
```

It is to be mentioned that, I am using this code after removing the libxmlsec1:armhf.list file from the directory /var/lib/dpkg/info and then reinstalling it by showing some tutorials from the internet. But I am getting the following error:

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxmlsec1:armhf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:files list file for package 'systemd-sysv' contains empty filename E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: "How can I solve this problem?" Restore from your backup.

Comment: Try an update. You have (for whatever reason) deleted the package information and what you are trying makes no sense.

Comment: have you tried without `--reinstall` since you messed around with package state?